# Preload views in Caliburn Micro

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I have a Caliburn.Micro application that runs on some rather slow panel PCs. The application is shaped like a wizard with several screens the user must go through. Since the computer running the application is slow, the first time each view is created, there is a noticeable delay.

Is there a way to preload or prerender the views, before actually showing them, so I can spend time in the application startup (which is already long due to other things) and avoid getting delays on the views?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure the problem is the rendering of the views and not the construction of the ViewModels?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth The viewmodels are constructed at startup already.

Comment: Are the views complex? Is it plausible that they take a long time to render?

Comment: They are not very complex, but the machine running the application is VERY slow, so I'd say it is, yes.

Comment: Load async and throw up a indeterminate progress indicator.  Having a dev spend a day on the problem probably costs more than a new computer :)

Comment: That's not really the point. These are embedded computers, so upgrading is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit about [OnViewReady](http://compiledexperience.com/blog/posts/using-on-view-ready-in-caliburn-micro).

Where is the data being loaded from and how is that happening, can you show that code?  Is it being loaded async so the view displays but the data is still loading?

It's probably possible to construct a view when the application is started, make it available to the `ViewModel`, and then override `GetView`.  If the views aren't complex as stated, it's probably the loading of the data.

Comment: There is no data being loaded. The panel PC running the application is really really slow, so just creating the view introduces a noticeable delay.

How would you go about manually construction the view? That's basically what I'm looking for.

Comment: I haven't tried this but you could try registering them in the bootstrapper and then injecting them into the ViewModel.  Then override GetView and return the injected View.  I'd have to look at the CM code to see if that would even work.

Comment: Interesting. I will give this a try.

Comment: Let me know, I can probably whip up and example.

Comment: Haven't gotten around to trying it yet. It's pretty low priority as the devices are supposed to be always on anyway, but if I do try it, I will let you know here.